# How to click an icon without clicking the image behind it?

Tags: html, css, overlay

I have an image with an icon on top if it:

```
<font-awesome-icon class="icons bookmark" icon="fa-solid fa-bookmark"></font-awesome-icon>
  <img :src="images[0]" @click.native="visit(l._id)" />
```

But on mobile devices, it ALWAYS clicks the image behind the icon. Is there a way to prevent this?

Here are my CSS classes:

```
<style scoped>
img {
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 8px;
    width: calc(100% - 50%);
}

.icons.bookmark {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 1em;
}

.icons.bookmark:hover {
    color: green;
}
</style>
```

here it is on the image:
[image: the icon on image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `pointer-events: all` on the icon. Check it out on the [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

I am not sure if this will solve your problem, because you said it only fails on mobile devices, but give it a try.